# Session doesn't work after redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect, header

My code looks like this:

```
...
$_SESSION['message']="something";
header('location:http://url/somewhere');
exit;
```

As you can see, I have an exit at the end of it. And that is the problem. It doesn´t work although I have an exit there.

I have this problem only on my localhost. At the online server it works well. In the errorlog it only shows "undefined index message". A few days ago I installed new Apache 2.4 and PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to start your session on every page you are going to use it:

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure to add "session_start();" to the beginning of every page that processes any sort of session data. Another thing to check would be to make sure you are setting the session variable properly. Also, when using header to redirect, make sure there is NO white space in the beginning of your document.

Comment: No this is not my problem and doesn´t solve my problem. I didn´t forget to write session_start() or send a white space before header().

Comment: Then I'd suggest you provide more information, because what your telling us doesn't give us a clue to what your problem could be.

Comment: This problem is normaly caused by absent exit() or die() command. But I have it as you can see. On online server it works. Only on my localhost - PHP 5.4 Apache 2.4 Win XP SP3 it lost session variables. Apache log write only - "undefined index" for any $_SESSION['vars'].

Comment: As a general rule - using Exit and Die() are bad practice. You should use logic to ensure that code isn't executed without having to use those calls. My last guess since you are using on your PC is to try uploading your code to a webhost to see if you can reproduce that problem. That would tell you if the issue is a local configuration or version problem, OR if it is a code problem.